# Let V be an upper triangular matrix and W and lower one, both of order n. How many operations in VW?

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, numerical-calculus

> Let V be an upper triangular matrix and W a lower triangular
> matrix, both square with n lines. Find the number of multiplications
> and additions performed to calculate the product VW.

When I multiply the first line of V by the cols of W I have

$$m = n; n-1; n-2; ... ; 1 = n^2-(n-1)!\\
a = n-1; n-1; n-3;...;0 = n^2-n!$$

For the second line

$$m = n-1; n-2; ...; 1 = n^2-(n-1)!\\
a = n-2; n-3; n-4;...;0 = n^2-n!$$

In total:

$$m = (n^2-(n-1)!)n \\
a = (n^2-n!)n$$

Is this correct?

Comment: If you do $n$ multiplications, then $n-1$, then $n-2$, and so on until you do $1$, then surely you do a total of $1+2+\cdots+n = n(n+1)/2$ multiplications. How do you get $n^2-(n-1)!$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin because n appears n times, so $n*n$. Then I have $n*n - (1+2+3+4+5+...+n-1)$... ok the factorial is wrong, how about $\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}k$ instead?

Comment: You are adding $1$, $2$, $3,\ldots,n$. That this sum is equal to $n(n+1)/2$ is well known.

Comment: Since $n^2-(n-1)!$ is negative whenever $n\geq 6$, you're getting a negative number of multiplications and an even more negative number of additions.

Answer (score 1):

With $V$ you have $v_{ij}=0$ if $i\gt j$.
With $W$ you have $w_{ij}=0$ if $i\lt j$.

If $VW=Z$, then
$$z_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n v_{ik}w_{kj}.$$
But whenever $k\lt \min(i,j)$, the summand is $0$. So the sum is really
$$z_{ij}=\sum_{k=\min(i,j)}^n v_{ik}w_{kj}.$$
This is $n+1-\min(i,j)$ products, and $n-\min(i,j)$ sums.

So you want to calculate
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (n+1)-\min(i,j).$$
And this in turn means calculating
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \min(i,j).$$
This sum is
$$1(n) + 2(n-1) + 3(n-2)+\cdots +n(1).$$
The calculation of the number of sums is going to likewise turn on this sum.